# PySpark: can not import PySpark in Jupyter Notebook

Tags: pyspark, jupyter-notebook

I installed both PySpark and Jupyter notebook on MacOS. From the terminal, I can open PySpark by typing`pyspark`. Then I want to use PySpark in the Jupyter Notebook, but it failed. I typed in the following code in Jupyter Notebook:

```
from pyspark.sql import SparkSession
```

I got the following error:

```
---------------------------------------------------------------------------
ModuleNotFoundError                       Traceback (most recent call last)
Cell In[1], line 2
      1 # import pyspark
----> 2 from pyspark.sql import SparkSession

ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'pyspark'
```

Any help is highly appreciated!

Comment: How exactly did you install pyspark and jupyter? Which Python do you use? (anaconda, virtualenv or just installed by brew or ??)

Comment: I am using Python 3.11.1. I installed pyspark and jupyter using brew.

Comment: You should check which kernel are you using in the jupyter notebook

Comment: @JonathanLam Yup. Good idea!

Answer (score 0):

I figured out the reason. Here I post the details, and hopefully they are useful to the community, especially the beginners of the PySpark, like myself:

When we install the Jupyter notebook and PySpark, by default, they are installed with the latest version. However, so far (2-Mar-2023 PT), PySpark (v3.3.2) only works well with Python 3.10 or lower. So, when I installed PySpark, I put it under the directory of Python 3.10, but the Jupyter notebook is installed with Python 3.11, and that is why the error message from my question is showing. Please let me know if there is anything unclear. Thank you for "brainstorming" with me, @Jonathan Lam and @AlexanderLedovsky! I love this forum!